Installing gem ffi 1.9.22 with M2 chip and Ruby 2.6.6
I tried installing ffi 1.9.22 on my terminal using the following command:
sudo gem install ffi -v '1.9.22'
I received the following error:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
When I scroll through the rest of the output, I keep seeing account for pc bias which makes me concerned that this version of ffi is too old for the M2 chip. Right now, I have Ruby Version 2.6.6 installed if this is relevant information.
The following is a list of solutions I've attempted:
brew install libffi

sudo LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig" gem install ffi -v '1.9.22'

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

gem install ffi -v 1.9.22

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi -v 1.9.22

sudo gem install ffi -v '1.9.22' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"

I get the same error with every command.
